# SOLR SynonymFilter and WordDelimiter problems

Tags: solr, lucene

**1. What I'm doing:**

I'm currently trying to implement some popular synonyms in order to increase the amount of ads displayed.

**2. Restrictions:**

Due to business logic, my default operator is AND so, as I understand it, searching for:

"ps3 slim 250gb new"

Should return items containing every single term in that query. I tried switching to 'OR' but that would return items with only the word 'new' or 'slim'.

Since we are always sorting by date and not by relevancy, this is a huge problem. So 'AND' it is.

The idea is to deal with this with lots of synonyms and stopwords.

**3. My set up:**

My current SOLR setup contains the following analyzer chain:

```
<fieldtype name="text_pt" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
       <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
       <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateWords="1" 
            catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="false" words="portugueseStopWords.txt"/>
       <filter class="solr.BrazilianStemFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
       <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="portugueseSynonyms.txt" 
                expand="true"/>
       <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="portugueseStopWords.txt"/>
       <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" 
                catenateWords="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.BrazilianStemFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

**4. The problem:**

I have the synonyms:

```
plaistation, plastation => playstation  #dirty spelling correction
ps3, playstation3  #just a synonym
```

The first one just works.
The second results in what seems to be a conflict between the synonym and the WordDelimiter, as seen in both the *analysis* page and the *&debugQuery*:

*Debug Query*

```
<str name="querystring">title_search_pt:(ps3)</str>
<str name="parsedquery">MultiPhraseQuery(title_search_pt:"(ps3 ps) (3 playstation3 playstation) 3")</str>
```

*Query Analyzer*

```
WhitespaceTokenizerFactory => [pos:1] ps3
ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory  => [pos:1] ps3
SynonymFilterFactory       => [pos:1] ps3 
                              [pos:1] playstation3

StopFilterFactory          => [pos:1] ps3 
                              [pos:1] playstation3

WordDelimiterFilterFactory => [pos:1] ps3  [pos:2] 3              [pos:3] 3
                              [pos:1] ps   [pos:2] playstation3
                                           [pos:2] playstation
```

As you can see it was all good until the WordDelimiterFilter messed it up. 
What I was expecting was *ps* and *playstation* both at pos:1 and then the 3 in pos:2.
This wouldn't be an issue if I had 'OR' as the default operation, but since it is not possible for me, this will try to match documents having BOTH ps3 and playstation3, which instead of giving me more results it's giving me even less..

**5. The question:**

What could I do about this? I think the WordDelimiterFilter gives a lot of good things to remove it altogether, but this token position shifting doesn't look right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using a nasty way of adding synonyms, exploiting the 'limitation' of phrase synonyms like this:

```
ps3 => playstation 3, ps 3
ps2 => playstation 2, ps 2
```

It's kind of a hack of using both a replacement (the =>) and a synonym (two words separated by comma).

The **Query Analyzer** goes like this:

```
WhitespaceTokenizerFactory => [pos:1] ps3
ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory  => [pos:1] ps3
SynonymFilterFactory       => [pos:1] ps            [pos:2] 3
                              [pos:1] playstation   [pos:2] 3

StopFilterFactory          => [pos:1] ps            [pos:2] 3
                              [pos:1] playstation   [pos:2] 3

WordDelimiterFilterFactory => [pos:1] ps            [pos:2] 3
                              [pos:1] playstation   [pos:2] 3
...
RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory =>  [pos:1] ps            [pos:2] 3
                                       [pos:1] playstation
```

And the **debugQuery**:

```
<str name="querystring">title_search_pt:(ps3 new)</str>
<str name="parsedquery">+MultiPhraseQuery(title_search_pt:"(playstation ps) 3") +title_search_pt:new</str>
```

I could drop one of the 3's from the synonyms because both 3's will end up at the same token position, and will be removed by the RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory. However I kept it like that so my synonyms file is less cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attribute `splitOnNumerics="0"` for the [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory)

> **splitOnNumerics="1"** causes alphabet => number transitions to generate a new part
>
> "j2se" => "j" "2" "se"
>
> default is true ("1"); set to 0 to turn off

That should remove the issue of it splitting up ps3 and playstation3 into two tokens, one with the word and one with the numeric value.

Comment: Yes but that wouldn't match searches like 'playstation 3', or 'iphone4', or 'nvidia 550ti'

Answer (score 0):

To complete your answer:

you could add all the words that you put in the synonyms (or only he one that give you problems) also in the `protwords.txt` file so that all the tokenizers will ignore them and just index them as they are.

This make sense if used in congiunction with a synonym file as a synonym is a word that you want to find as it is.